# Making content and functions maintainable in the long run

Tags: theming

I've been playing around with drupal for a couple of weeks now and one subsisting doubt remains in my mind: what is the correct, 'Drupal' way to add your custom content? For basic text and links, a WYSIWYG editor that I've downloaded seems to be only about adequate (as it is a bit sluggish).

Because I want to extend website functionalities, like user input, I've been using `.tpl.php` files to modify content on specific nodes/blocks. For example, in some arbitrary file along the lines of`mytheme/templates/page--block--5.tpl.php` there is code that prints to that page, like so

`<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
<div>
<?php my code here... ?>
</div>`

But this isn't great for the future of this project as it's essentially hard-coding. Given that I will probably one day have several people uploading content or pass it on to a different admin, what's the right way to add more advanced features for maintainability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Drupal world, this is what we refer to as [Site Building](http://buildamodule.com/collection/advanced-site-building-in-drupal-7). Site building is the process of using contributed modules to help you achieve something without throwing a bunch of code into a template (big no-no for the most part).

For example, you can use Views for building dynamic lists of content, Display Suite and Panels for node layouts, Webform to capture user input, Radioactivity to rank popular content, the list goes on and on. Unless you're doing something very specific, you can usually find a module that can assist you in building out features on your site.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it's not recommended to code in a template? As I said, I have a feeling it isn't right but it also seems like the only way I can elicit the behavior I would like _(e.g. putting a body/table/image in a block that doesn't have such a field and has no obvious way of adding it in the admin menu either)_

Comment: To make custom Blocks for example, you can use a module called [BEAN (Block Entities Aren't Nodes)](http://drupal.org/project/bean). This allows you to take to same concept as a node (adding fields, displays, etc) and apply it to blocks. Now you can have new types of blocks, like an image block or even a slideshow block.

Like I said, there is just a multitude of modules you can use to help you achieve things like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Block content can be held in the DB. `.tpl.php` files are as the name suggests used for templates. E.g. block.tpl.php is the template for all blocks.

If you have 2 distinct type of template for blocks then you could certainly create a block-alternate.tpl.php but there is certainly no need to create specific templates per block.

If you want to alter user input then add fields to your custom content types, or maybe look at the [Webform module](https://drupal.org/project/webform).